# React Conditional Rendering of Component Inside Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am using Codesandbox to work on learning React. I am trying to conditionally render a functional React component inside of a function (inside of a class based component), that fires when a button is clicked.

Here is the link to the Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/laughing-butterfly-mtjrq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The issue I have is that, without importing and rendering the Error and Meals in App.js, I never can get either component to render from the Booking component. In the function here:

```
   if (!this.state.name) {
     return (
       <div>
         <Error />
       </div>
     );
   }
    else {
      return <Meals name={this.state.name} date={this.state.date} />;
    }
 }
```

I should be rendering Error, which should then show on the screen on click if no name is inputted but nothing happens and I am stumped.

Is there anything obvious that would be preventing me from seeing the Error component from loading on the click?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that is displayed on the screen comes from `render` method. You cann't return `JSX` from any function like that. You can do something like this:

```
class Bookings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      date: "",
      display: false
    };
  }

  guestInfoHandler = event => {
    console.log(this.state, "what is the state");
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  dateInfoHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ date: event.target.value });
  };

  showMeals = () => {
    this.setState({ display: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
     <>
      <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
        <form
          className="theForm"
          style={{
            height: "50px",
            width: "100px",
            borderColor: "black",
            borderWidth: "1px"
          }}
        >
          <label className="theLabel">
            Name:
            <input
              className="theInput"
              type="text"
              placeholder="guest name here"
              onChange={this.guestInfoHandler}
              value={this.state.value}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
        <form>
          <label>
            Date:
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="date here"
              onChange={this.dateInfoHandler}
              value={this.state.value}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => this.showMeals()}>Click</button>
      </div>
      { display && name ? (
          <Meals name={name} date={name} />
          ) : (
             <Error />
          )}
     </>
    );
  }
}

export default Bookings;
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, this does work! This is so helpful and makes much more sense. I didn't think adding JSX in a function seemed right, but I found a few articles on conditional rendering that used that as an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
  render() {
      const name = this.state.name;
      return (
        <div>
          {name ? (
          <Meals name={name} date={name} />
          ) : (
             <Error />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

nb:use render method in class component only.

there is various types conditional rendering mentioned in

[https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#___gatsby)